# How do i pass in the arguments for DateTime so it corresponds to the required formal Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, properties

How do I pass in the arguments for DateTime so it corresponds to the required formal parameter? Int, string and double are NO problem, but this is giving me true headache.

```
class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }

    public static DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public static DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

    public Activity(int id, int minAge, int maxAge, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        MinAge = minAge;
        MaxAge = maxAge;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Activity ak1 = new Activity(1, 15, 21, ?, ?); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use DateTime.Now or new DateTime(2000, 11, 26), for example.

Comment: I did your last option and it was exactly what i was looking for, ty so much man!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to send parameter of type `DateTime`. So you can send `DateTime.Now` or if you have date, then just [use overloading of constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) like this `new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)`

Comment: Using overloading of constructor was exactly what i was looking for, tyvm!!